# How to add integers to Resources in windows library

Tags: c#, .net, class, resources

Is there a way to store integers in the resource properties in a class library?

As of now it looks as if I'd have to store them as strings and do a int.Parse(Resource.Width);

Any suggestions?

[image: Resource View]

Comment: Resources are meant for storing strings.

Comment: got a recommendation as to where I can store ints that are common across a few libraries?

Comment: some class with a bunch of public const int properties maybe?